# Write a query to select one of rows that have same column data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Test) with below data

```
code  Name   relatedCode

   1    A         0
   2    B         1
   3    C         1
   4    D         0
```

I want to write a query to select :

```
1   A
2   B
4   D
```

means beetween row 2,3 that have same relatedCode just select one of them

Comment: I edited it and find answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  code, name
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY relatedCode ORDER BY code) rn
        FROM    test
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make it `Select code, name From test Where relatedCode = 0`? Because any non-zero would eventually route back to a base level code part?